# Separation axioms

Tags: separation-axioms, gn.general-topology

Reading about separation axioms, I wonder:
Is there a separation axiom weaker than $T_2$ but stronger than $T_1$? $T_{1.5}$?
I suppose there are some separation axioms stronger that $T_6$, how many are there?

Comment: For instance you may consider "discrete", that we may call $T_7$ or maybe $T_\infty$

Comment: For any space $X$ with more than one point one may consider the separation axiom "any two points can be distinguished by a continuous function to $X$." 

Comment: I briefly considered the notion of separating arbitrary large disjoint subsets (where each set needed at least kappa elements).  However, I can't distinguish this property from the space being discrete.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.01.27

Comment: @yuan: that property is called completely Hausdorff, and is stronger than Hausdorff, not weaker.

Answer (score 6):

There is a separation axiom between $T_1$ and $T_2$ that Aull (Separation of bicompact sets, *Math. Annalen* **158** (1965), 197–202) calls $J_1$ and that Mukherji (On weak Hausdorff spaces, *Bull. Calcutta Math. Soc.* **58** (1966), 153–157) calls $T_2'$; namely, "every compact subspace is closed."  Such spaces are sometimes called "weak Hausdorff spaces," although this term is sometimes used to mean something else.  See Hoffmann (On weak Hausdorff spaces, *Arch. Math. (Basel)* **32** (1979), 487–504) for further discussion of other separation axioms between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Comment: Wilansky introduced KC (all compact sets are closed) and US (every convergent sequence has a unique limit) in the paper "between T1 and T2", American mathematical monthly, 74(1967), 261-264. We then have $T_2$ implies KC implies US implies $T_1$, and all implications cannot be reversed in general.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked into this before, and I never heard of $T_{1.5}$. However, there are notions of $R_0$ and $R_1$ which can combine to get the usual $T$-separation axioms. For instance, a space is $T_1$ iff it is $R_0$ and $T_0$. A space is $T_2$ iff both $T_0$ and $R_1$. This might give you some ideas for how to create a $T_{1.5}$ if you wanted to. A good reference is the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) on the separation axioms.

Another notion below $T_2$ but above $T_0$ is that of a [sober space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space). Perhaps this will work for whatever application you have in mind.

As for "above" $T_6$, I think at that level you are basically at being a metric space. Recall that a metric space satisfies all the separation axioms, and recall the [Metrization Theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem) about how close the various separation axioms are to implying metrizability. Every discrete topology is metrizable, so I'd put that past metrizable on the scale, as perhaps the ``nicest'' space possible.